# Updating LAS Classification: Correcting Misclassified Vegetation Points

Tags: lidr

I have two las files: *abc* and *xyz*. The LASGROUND class in *abc* have some misclassified vegetation points while the *xyz* have those correctly classified vegetation points. Now I want to update the classification of *abc* using *xyz* point (or their geometry). I am using following code:

First let me explain how I obtained *xyz* file with just vegetation points

```
rgb_values <- abc@data[, c("R", "G", "B")]
### Calculate vegetation index
veg_index <- (2 * rgb_values[, "G"] - rgb_values[, "R"] - rgb_values[, "B"]) /
  (2 * rgb_values[, "G"] + rgb_values[, "R"] + rgb_values[, "B"])
### Now to add the it to lidar as attribute first make it as vector
veg_index_vector <- as.numeric(veg_index$G)
laz_veg <- add_lasattribute_manual(abc, veg_index_vector, "Veg_index", "VI",type="float")
### Filtering out vegetation points from ground class
corrected = filter_poi(laz_veg , Veg_index > 0.03, Classification == 2L)
```

Now moving ahead with updating classification of *abc* using *corrected/xyz*

```
abc= readLAS('misclassified.laz')
xyz= readLAS('corrected.laz')

las = LAS(rbind(abc, xyz))
```

The above code definitely does the job of adding those vegetation points as I could see increase in number of vegetation points in *las*. However, the above code results in duplicate points in the merged LAS file, and removing duplicates using filter_duplicates leads to the loss of vegetation points again.

```
try_dup = filter_duplicates(las)
```

I want to update the classification of misclassified ground points in *abc* using corrected vegetation points from *xyz*. How can I achieve this without losing data?

Comment: Are the files exactly the same? I mean the same xyz but only different classification? Have you tried the same but merging in the opposite order: `las = LAS(rbind(xyz, abc))`

Comment: Oh great, that simply worked!! Thanks :)